# Why this code works differently in Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use this code to set a value in a view even if current_user doesn't exist. If you know a better way suggest an alternative bc many method I use raise an exception otherwise.

```
def setval_if(valgood, valbad=nil)
  begin
    return valgood if yield
  rescue
  else
  end
end

setval_if("no exception raised") { true }
# => "no exception raised" # my machine, correct.
# => nil # Heroku
```

but If I add this dirty hack it works also in heroku

```
def setval_if(valgood, valbad=nil)
  begin
    return valgood if yield
    puts "suca vaff.."
  rescue
  else
  end
end

setval_if("no exception raised") { true }
# => "no exception raised" # my machine, correct.
# => "no exception raised" # Heroku
```

why why why???? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue related to the version of Ruby that is being run.  I can replicate this same issue on my local machine with rvm under ruby-1.9.2-p320.

I ran the code on Heroku against one of my apps and the error did not occur; that particular app was running on ruby-1.9.3-p194

Can you confirm which Heroku stack you are running on?  To do this simply login to heroku, then run the following

heroku stack -a yourappnamehere

I ran the test under the latest heroku stack; cedar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm on Cedar too, but > ENV['RUBYOPT']
=> "-I/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib -rbundler/setup" Why do you have 1.9.3 and I'm on ruby 1.9.1???

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I've been off the grid hunting for the last couple of days.  1.9.1 must be the default Ruby version for the Cedar stack then.  It looks like I specified 1.9.3 in my Gemfile.